# VirtualBox guest hangs when: Starting Apparmor profiles

Tags: ubuntu, boot, apparmor

I have a Fedora 14. I installed the Ubuntu 11.04 i386 mini.iso in Virtualbox. After install when I reboot it it just hangs with this message:

```
/dev/mapper/vg-root: tiszta, 52354/5103616 fájl, 559633/20408320 blokk
init: ureadahead-other main process (420) terminated with status 4
[   14.569632] piix_smbus 0000:00:07.0: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
 * Starting AppArmor profiles    [ OK ]
```

First line translates from Hungarian to English as:

```
/dev/mapper/vg-root: clean, 52354/5103616 files, 559633/20408320 blocks
```

What should I do to boot this Ubuntu guest? Is it a bug?

If I switch to another tty then I can see the log in screen/terminal and I can log in too. Ohh well, it's just a test guest vm. I hope when it comes to installing Ubuntu minimal on a real machine, it won't stop at the apparmor message.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pressing <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comments on [this Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/522197) seem to indicate that the "ureadahead-other" and AppArmor messages are essentially unrelated to what's happening, but the real message or prompt you should be seeing is being swallowed or preempted by that error message.

The keys above are just the most likely to let you proceed beyond the problems that occur at this point in the boot process, but again, the real issue is that the prompt you should seeing is not being printed. People generally report that the prompts appear correctly if you enable Upstart quiet boot (the "quiet" boot arg).

Comment: I tried S and Enter, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

This problem can happen when your `hosts` file doesn't have an entry for your machine's hostname. I would recommend fixing `hosts` and rebooting.